# How to construct a 2 bytes or short from DateTime.Now.Date only value? YYYYmmDD

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, datetime, byte

I see some guys do following to store Date to 2 bytes only (ushort)!, not 4 bytes (int)

Assume that format `yyyyMMdd`:   `20220521`, Fit into 1 short and 1 byte. or 1 integer only. But next code I just copied it from decompiled source. (Not understand how he manipulate bits....)

In my opinion. It can be 1 byte for last digit of year (2022 will stored as 22 byte) + 1 short for month, day.... But I failed to make it just 2 bytes like below example.

**I don't even understand how they achieve it... I don't understand how next code works. Wish to understand how he think to do that...**

```
   private byte[] PackDate16(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date.Year < 2000 || date.Year > 2127)
                throw new Exception("Invalid year for a 16-bit date. Allowed values are 2010-2127");
            ushort num = (ushort)(date.Year - 2000 << 9 | date.Month << 5 | date.Day);
            return new byte[2]
            {
        (byte) ((uint) num & (uint) byte.MaxValue),
        (byte) ((uint) num >> 8)
            };
        }
```

After do some search... I found https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/661377-c-program-convert-2-byte-time-2-byte-date-datetime

Are there any Bit library to do that easily?

Comment: Optimizations such as this is literally why we had Y2K.  Do you truly need this performance optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you manipulate with bits at all if you can just add and subtract days?

```
private static short CompressMe(DateTime value, DateTime minDate) =>
  (short)((value - minDate).Days + short.MinValue);

private static DateTime DeCompressMe(short value, DateTime minDate) =>
  minDate.AddDays(value - short.MinValue);
```

For Instance:

```
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

// -24592
var result = CompressMe(new DateTime(2022, 5, 21), minDate);
// 6 June 2179
DateTime maxDate = DeCompressMe(short.MaxValue, minDate);
```

So far so good you can represent dates as `short` if they in

```
1 Jan 2000 .. 6 Jun 2179
```

period

Comment: Very nice solution dear. Would you mind to help on how to do same thing for compress bytes into single 1 byte. with AND,OR logical things that am leaks :(  
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332148/how-to-compress-length-of-4-bytes-to-fit-into-1-byte-only-of-tag-length-value-st

Comment: `byte` can represent values in `0..255` range only, please, note that `256` days are less than `1` year. I doubt if compressing `DateTime` into `byte` has any reason at all.

Comment: Sure. I apply your code and happy with it :)  -But I change from `short` to `ushort` and reverse equation, for my comment I speak for other problem for compress strings in the link I port :)