# How to compress Length of 4 Bytes to fit into 1 Byte only of Tag-Length-Value stream?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, byte, tlv

I see this [guy](https://github.com/cgreenza/TlvLib/blob/master/TlvLib/TlvEncoding.cs) do something different for Tag-Length-Value, He allow to store large length > 255, As we see in TLV examples it working like that:

I need to store My ID + Name

Tag 1, Length 5, Value (ID) = 12345, and so on

Back again to what I need, How this guy/[TlvEncoding](https://TlvEncoding) compress the length to allow store more than 4 bytes. he something with AND, OR binary logical operators with 127 for example:

Assume that I have string of length 1000, Which exceed 1 byte. He do following

Note: 0xffff = 65,535 maximum value of `UInt16` or `ushort`. I think condition when length 1000 will met on that line. and stream will write 2 bytes for length. But when he read that value he do more logical manipulation. which am already leaks. :(

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Write TLV length to stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">stream to write to</param>
    /// <param name="length">length to write or null to write indefinite length</param>
    public static void WriteLength(Stream stream, int? length)
    {
        if (length == null)
        {
            stream.WriteByte(0x80); // indefinite form
            return;
        }

        if (length < 0 || length > 0xffffffff)
            throw new TlvException(string.Format("Invalid length value: {0}", length));

        if (length <= 0x7f) // use short form if possible
        {
            stream.WriteByte(checked((byte)length));
            return;
        }

        byte lengthBytes;

        // use minimum number of octets
        if (length <= 0xff)
            lengthBytes = 1;
        else if (length <= 0xffff)
            lengthBytes = 2;
        else if (length <= 0xffffff)
            lengthBytes = 3;
        else if (length <= 0xffffffff)
            lengthBytes = 4;
        else
            throw new TlvException(string.Format("Length value too big: {0}", length));

        stream.WriteByte((byte)(lengthBytes | 0x80));

        // shift out the bytes
        for (var i = lengthBytes - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var data = (byte)(length >> (8 * i));
            stream.WriteByte(data);
        }
    }
```

In read operation he do: ( I think condition will met here `0x7f; // remove 0x80 bit`)
I don't know exactly why he choose 0x7f which equals 127, and he remove 0x80 that equal 128.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read TLV length from stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">Stream to read</param>
    /// <returns>length or null to indicate indefinite length</returns>
    public static int? ReadLength(Stream stream)
    {
        var readByte = stream.ReadByte();
        if (readByte == -1)
            throw new TlvException("Unexpected end of stream while reading length");

        if ((readByte & 0x80) == 0)
            return (int)readByte; // length is in first byte

        int length = 0;
        var lengthBytes = readByte & 0x7f; // remove 0x80 bit

        if (lengthBytes == 0)
            return null; // indefinite form

        if (lengthBytes > 4)
            throw new TlvException($"Unsupported length: {lengthBytes} bytes");

        for (var i = 0; i < lengthBytes; i++)
        {
            readByte = stream.ReadByte();
            if (readByte == -1)
                throw new TlvException("Unexpected end of stream while reading length");

            length <<= 8;
            length |= (int)readByte;
        }

        return length;
    }
```

Please I just need to understand how things going on there, Because I need to apply same method in an array of bytes. I need to store i.e: string of 1500 length, datetime, some integers, as (TLVs). But All I know is how to apply only 1 byte length (255).

So I can only read length of 1 byte, Because  I don't know how to tell array that I need to seek for length of 3 bytes? or 2 bytes? I must then store all TLVs with 2 or 3 bytes. That a waste of space.

1. Integer stored as 4 bytes (OK), So I can write Length is `(byte) 4` **(note byte cast)**
2. String can stored only in **255**, But how to do it like above guy? 1500 length in 3 bytes?

Simply I explain it, He allow to store 1 byte as length, sometimes 3 bytes as length. I don't even know how he can tell compiler/stream to read this tag length from next 3 bytes. or next 2 bytes. or 1 byte.

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356153/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-short-number-that-less-or-equal-1000-to-1-byte-wit ?

Comment: Because its already answered, people said impossible :)

Comment: Then post that answer and let the question remain - this site is all about creating questions and answers for ***future*** readers.

Comment: Yes for sure dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `WriteLength`, it looks fairly simple.

Values between 0 and 0x7F inclusive are just represented by a single byte with that value. So if you want to write e.g. the value `5`, you write a byte with the value `5`.

For values > 0x7F:

1. The first byte is the number of bytes needed to represent the value, with the highest-bit set (so that you can tell the difference between it and a simple byte which holds a value between 0-127)
2. The next however-many bytes hold the actual value.

| Value | Serialized |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0x00 |
| 1 | 0x01 |
| 127 | 0x7F |
| 128 | 0x81 0x80 |
| 129 | 0x81 0x81 |
| 255 | 0x81 0xFF |
| 256 | 0x82 0x01 0x00 |
| 257 | 0x82 0x01 0x01 |
| 65535 | 0x82 0xFF 0xFF |
| 65536 | 0x83 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 |

And so on...

Comment: thank you much for your effort and descriptive information, But I wish if you can provide a integral way to achieve same result without hexadecimal, I never deal with shift, bitwise operators in my life, Do you have a way to implement WriteLength() with normal numeric comparison rather than hexadecimal, and without bitwise and shifts?  :(

Comment: I will be happy if it can achieved without shift and bitwise operators :(  see here  https://prnt.sc/KKHQwO7Nczd9,  Maybe if..else condition with integer numbers?

Comment: You can just convert each hex number to decimal if you want -- but hex was chosen for a reason, and that reason is that it's a lot easier to work with when you're doing bitwise manipulation. You're doing bit-level manipulation here, and the bitwise operations are the right tools to use. If you're not comfortable with them, then this is the time to get comfortable, rather than trying to avoid them

Comment: I can understand ReadLength function(), But WriteLength(), I don't know why he loop in reversed array... Endianess?

Comment: Yeah. They decided to write the most significant byte first. If the loop was up-counting, it would write the least significant byte first